# Can a Christian convert marry a non-Christian girl under Indian Christian Marriage Act?

Tags: marriage, religious-law, indian-constitutional-law, conversion

I am a Christian in India who recently got converted from Hinduism. I am in love with a woman who's a Hindu. I was thinking about marrying her in the Church I am a member of, but she pointed out that the marriage might not be possible since Churches in India allowed marriages between Christians only. However, I was going through the Indian Christian Marriage Act of 1872 and I noticed that this particular marriage act was applicable even for a marriage where at least one party was Christian. Now she doesn't want to convert and I don't want her to convert just for the sake of marriage. So I have the following questions:

1. Can I marry her under Indian Christian Marriage Act or is Special Marriage Act the only option?
2. My whole family is Hindu and I am the only convert. Will that be a problem for my marriage if I'm allowed to marry under Indian Christian Marriage Act?
3. What will be the religion of our kid according to the law in India?

Thanks for your time